# How can I change the text color of this content page?

Tags: maui

I seem to be having an issue changing the text color of this content page. Changing the text color of my title in mainpage was a breeze but this WelcomePage I setup seems to not be cooperating.

Here's the code for my AppShell

```xml
<Shell
    x:Class="WhatShouldYouWear.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    Shell.TitleColor="Black"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WhatShouldYouWear"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled">

    <ShellContent
        Title="RobeWhiz" 
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
        Route="MainPage" />
</Shell>
```

And for my WelcomePage.xaml

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="WhatShouldYouWear.WelcomePage"
             Title="Welcome to 'RobeWhiz'!"
             Shell.TitleColor="Black">
```

Comment: Is your *WelcomePage* part of the Shell view hierarchy? When and how do you set that page? I'm asking, because there are different answers on how it's instantiated and displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You could define your own Shell TitleView:

```
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="WhatShouldYouWear.WelcomePage"
    Shell.BackgroundColor="DarkGreen">

    <Shell.TitleView>
        <HorizontalStackLayout VerticalOptions="Fill">
            <Label Text="Welcome to MAUI" FontFamily="Strande2" TextColor="White" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HeightRequest="50" FontSize="Medium" />
        </HorizontalStackLayout>
    </Shell.TitleView>

</ContentPage>
```

How to custom Navigation TitleView (top bar)

```
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="WhatShouldYouWear.WelcomePage"
    Shell.BackgroundColor="DarkGreen">

    <NavigationPage.TitleView>    
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"  Orientation="Horizontal">    
            <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Text="Refresh" FontSize="Small"/>    
            <Image VerticalOptions="Center"  HorizontalOptions="End" Source="sync.png"/>    
        </StackLayout>    
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>    
</ContentPage>
```

You can also define your own global styles and colors using theming and styles to reuse them...

for more information about theming check :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/theming

for more information about styling check :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/styles/xaml

Answer (score 0):

A good way to handle all your need for design regarding colours is to use [Style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/styles/xaml)

Examples in your AppShell.xmal:

```xml
<Shell.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="Element">
            <Setter Property="Shell.BackgroundColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Dark={StaticResource DarkBackgroundColor}, Light={StaticResource LightBackgroundColor}}" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.ForegroundColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Dark={StaticResource DarkForegroundColor}, Light={StaticResource LightForegroundColor}}" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.TitleColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Dark={StaticResource DarkFontColor}, Light={StaticResource LightFontColor}}" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.DisabledColor" Value="#B4FFFFFF" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.UnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Dark={StaticResource DarkBackgroundColor}, Light={StaticResource LightBackgroundColor}}" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarForegroundColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Dark={StaticResource DarkForegroundColor}, Light={StaticResource LightForegroundColor}}" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Dark=#E7E7E7, Light=#CCCCCC}" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarTitleColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Dark={StaticResource DarkForegroundColor}, Light={StaticResource LightForegroundColor}}" />
        </Style>
        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" TargetType="TabBar" />
        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" TargetType="FlyoutItem" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Shell.Resources>
```

Define your colors [globaly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/styles/xaml#global-styles) in the App.xaml like this:

```xml
<Color x:Key="LightBackgroundColor">#FFFFFF</Color>
<Color x:Key="DarkBackgroundColor">#222222</Color>
<Color x:Key="LightForegroundColor">#222222</Color>
<Color x:Key="DarkForegroundColor">#FFFFFF</Color>
<Color x:Key="LightFontColor">#222222</Color>
<Color x:Key="DarkFontColor">#E7E7E7</Color>
<Color x:Key="LightSeparatorColor">#222222</Color>
<Color x:Key="DarkSeparatorColor">#E7E7E7</Color>
```